# PHP preg_match - correct pattern

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

I need help with my script.I'm trying to parse a specific value from a website, but I can't find the correct pattern for preg_match in PHP

I got this

```
(?)</a></div><div class="covSmallHeadline" style="font-weight:normal;width:100px;float:left;text-align:right;color:black;font-weight:bold">1.22</div>
```

From which I want to get the value of **1.22**

```
    preg_match("/</a></div><div class=\"covSmallHeadline\" style=\"font-weight:normal;width:100px;float:left;text-align:right;color:black;font-weight:bold\">(.*?)</div>/i", $data, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

This is what I have, but its not working

Comment: Have you tried a HTML parser instead? Regex is a shitty tool for what you are doing...

Comment: I prefer not to use the HTML parser

Comment: You can test your pattern in @ https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

Comment: Is it always a number in decimal format?

Comment: Yes, its always a number in this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>(\d*.\d*)<
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XB_zxB1j2JaOn5R3)

This is the cutest regex I've ever seen. :)

Comment: thank for the fast reply, but that doesn't work for me ;/

Comment: It works in the debug tool, using the text you provided. What didn't work?

Comment: So I changed my code to `preg_match(">(\d*.\d*)<", $data, $match);` and it gives me error 500 - No ending delimiter '>', I'm quite new to parsing in php

Comment: You need to add delimiters to the pattern. `"/>(\d*.\d*)</"`

Comment: Next time, don't just say "doesn't work". Cause either the person will give up trying to help you, or they'll have to ask the obvious question, and you'll have to explain with useful info anyway.